# iOS localization inconsistency

Tags: xcode, ios, localization

I'm localizing an iPhone app for the first time. I've put all my strings into a `Localizable.strings` file, accessing them via `NSLocalizedString` from within my code. Works fine.
Next, I have a file called `info.html` that contains the flesh of a `UIWebView` that I use as an About box. I've put it in the language folders (`en.lproj` and `de.lproj`), and added them to my Resources in Xcode. 
Now, in Simulator, both the Strings, and the html file display in the appropriate language.
However, on the device, the Strings appear localized while the html file remains untranslated.

This is a strange inconsistency between Simulator and Device! Anybody know of a workaround? (...other than defying the localization system, and using `NSLocalizedString` to call `de_info.html`, `en_info.html` etc. by hand.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to delete the app first.

When you use Xcode to deploy to the device (or simulator) resources are only added, not removed.
Most likely now you have three html files. One in the `de` folder, one in the `en` folder and one in the root folder.

And if it's there iOS prefers the one in the root folder.

As a general rule: When you remove (or like in this case move them around) resources from your project, you should delete the app from the device or the simulator.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah. (Sound usually made after staring at IKEA installation instructions for half an hour.) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Another addition: I also needed to remove the app from my current build directory to make it work (otherwise, the deleted app on the device was then replaced with the wrong version again).

In XCode you can press the 'alt' key within the 'Build' menu and then you have the option to clean the whole build directory.

That finally solved the issue for me. Sigh...

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "Clean Build Folder" option. I ran into the same problem and a simple "Clean" + deleting the app from the simulator did not appear to solve the issue after removing a XIB localization. This solved the problem for me.