# Localizable.strings files is shown in RED color in Copy Bundle Resources Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios7, localization, internationalization, xcode5.1

My iOS app supports total 6 languages. I have 6 different language files in my project. Everything works perfectly but my Localizable.strings files for all language except "English" shown in RED color Copy Bundle Resources Xcode 5.1. I have used ibtool to create the .strings file.

I searched on Google & got different posts but none of the solution works for me.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744748/moving-lproj-file-inside-resources) , I validated my project settings & popup shows "Project settings are valid with green checkmark"

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063993/ios7-multiple-storyboard-localization-issue) solution as well but no luck.

Here are the screenshots of my Xcode

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I change the language on iPhone to Polish or any supported language , I can see translated strings in the app. Everything works perfectly.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in project setting ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how **ibtool** works. But as I see, you've added **xx.lproj** folders to your project. And that's why you see them red in Copy Bundle Resources section.
Try to add each ***.strings** file singly.[image]

This is what you'll see if you add them correctly.